# c++ win32 api notify mouse inside button area

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, button

I've a Button made using Win32Api that I want to be able to notify whenever the user put the mouse inside the button rectangle.
I noticed that when user does that the WM_NOTIFY is called but I don't know which flag to use for ensure that the user has the mouse inside it's area.

Here is my button:

```
HWND Button = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "Test",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | BS_NOTIFY,
        20, 240, 120, 20,
        hwnd, (HMENU)101, NULL, NULL);
```

And my WndProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_NOTIFY:
    {
        //??? Here is where I want to do it
    }
    case WM_CREATE: //On Window Create
    {
        wHWND = hwnd;
        if (onCreate != NULL)
            onCreate(hwnd);
        break;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND: //Command execution
    {
        //...
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY: //Form Destroyed
    {
        if (onDestroy != NULL)
            onDestroy(hwnd);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I don't know if I'm in the right path using WM_NOTIFY or not, maybe there is an easier way to do that. Thank you!

Comment: How do you focus a button with the mouse?

Comment: Putting it inside his rectangle

Comment: That does not change focus.

Comment: In vc++ and c# there is a method to know when the mouse is inside the button rectangle, maybe it's not called focus (If so my bad, I got it from another platform) but there is a method to know that and I want to implement it here for changing button apperance when it happens.

Comment: You need to make it clear in the question. With an edit. As it stands this is a waste of time for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try catching the [`WM_SETFOCUS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646283(v=vs.85).aspx) message instead if you want a generic way of tracking focus.

`BN_SETFOCUS` is sent as `WM_COMMAND` in the upper 16 bits of WPARAM (`HIWORD`):

> The parent window of the button receives this notification code through the WM_COMMAND message

If you are not talking about focus but just the mouse position then you can use `ChildWindowFromPointEx` or `RealChildWindowFromPoint` and a timer.

Comment: BN_SETFOCUS as far as I know is for keyboard focus and the WM_SETFOCUS never tells if the button has it. I want to know when the button has focus for changing it's apperance

Comment: Call GetFocus() when you get WM_SETFOCUS

Comment: It'll always return window HWND even if I put the cursor inside the button rectangle

Comment: You asked about focus and I told you about focus, if you are talking about just the mouse position then use RealChildWindowFromPoint.